# Laravel 5.8 scss compiling Expected ":". error

Tags: laravel, sass

I am developing a Laravel project running on localhost with `php artisan serve`, when I run `npm run watch` command to compile sass code I get the error `Expected ":".` at the beginning of the app.scss

The error is:

```
$import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
   ^
  Expected ":".
  ╷
2 │ $import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
  │         ^
  ╵
  stdin 3:9  root stylesheet
      in C:\Users\user\Documents\myApp\resources\sass\app.scss (line 3, column 9)
```

the app.scss first 6 lines are:

```
// Fonts
$import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
$import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');

// Variables
$import 'variables';
```

I don't see where are missing the ":". I never used ":" in the @import directive

What am I missing? why am I getting this error? How to solve it?

- Laravel 5.8.35
- Windows 10 pro 17763.737
- PHP Version 7.1.29
- Composer version 1.8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be an `@` in front of the import:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

---

Variables have an `$` in front of them and need `:` after them to give them a value. The compiler thinks you are creating an `$import` variable in your case, that's why it expects a `:`.